# Loop error when reading a list of files in Panda

Tags: pandas

I want to use a loop to read several files from a list. If I put the list in the file path field, it gives an error. I want to know why.

```
import pandas as pd

file_list = [aaa.csv, bbb.csv, ccc.csv]

for n in range(2):

    train[n] = pd.read_csv("file_list[n]")
```

Results in this error:

> File b'file_list[n]' does not exist.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently trying to open the file that is literally called `file_list[n]`, and there is no such file. Try instead:

```
train[n] = pd.read_csv(file_list[n])
      # no quotes here ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you leave out the quotes, the expression `file_list[n]` will evaluate to the n-th filename from your list, and that file will be opened.

Please note that this might still fail because your variable `train` is not initialized. So you might start with a `train = []` to create an empty list, and then `append` new elements to that list. Your code then looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file_list = ['aaa.csv', 'bbb.csv', 'ccc.csv']
train = []

for n in range(2):
    train.append(pd.read_csv(file_list[n]))
```

And if you want to be really hardcore you can even write

```
import pandas as pd

train = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in ['aaa.csv', 'bbb.csv', 'ccc.csv']]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.


Additionally,
What if I need to specify the parent folder in front of the file path instead of just the list name?


train[n] = pd.read_csv("C:/download/file_list[n]")


You can not omit quotes if you specify this parent path.


I need your help.

Comment: The best way to do this is using `os.path.join`: start with `import os` at the top of the script and then when you read the file say `pd.read_csv(os.path.join("C:/download/", file_list[n]))`